# How set keyboard event to one shape at a time using Konva

Tags: javascript, konva

I have a stage with a lot of shapes, and I would like to move one shape using the keyboard UP, Down, Left, and Right when it is clicked. The implementation was working for one element, but when I have more than one, all elements are moved when keydown is pressed.I found an example on the Konva site, bat it works for one element. I try to remove the event when the mouse was moving waiting for the next click in some shape element, but it doesn't work too. How  I can do it?

My code

```
 <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
      var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });

      var layer = new Konva.Layer();
      stage.add(layer);

      var circle = new Konva.Circle({
        x: stage.width() / 2,
        y: stage.height() / 2 + 10,
        radius: 70,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
      });

      layer.add(circle);
      
      var rect = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 300,
        y: 10,
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        stroke: 'black',
        fill: 'blue',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        cornerRadius: 2,
        id: 'cRectSquare',
        visible: true,
        draggable: true,
      });

      layer.add(rect);
     
     //add event keydown 
     stage.on('click', function (e) {

       if (e.target === stage) {
         return;
       }

       let currentShape = e.target;
       AddKeyboardEventToShape(currentShape);
     });
      
     stage.on('mousemove', function (e) {

       var container = stage.container();
       container.tabIndex = 0;
       container.focus(false);
       container.off('keydown');

       container.removeEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
       });

       return;
     }); 
      
     function AddKeyboardEventToShape(shape){

       var container = stage.container();

       container.tabIndex = 1;
       container.focus();

       var DELTA = 3;

       container.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {

         if (e.keyCode === 37) {
           shape.x(shape.x() - DELTA);
         } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
           shape.y(shape.y() - DELTA);
         } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
           shape.x(shape.x() + DELTA);
         } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
           shape.y(shape.y() + DELTA);
         } else {
           return;
         }
         e.preventDefault();
       });
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: I think that keyboard events should be "global" and not attached or detached to this or that element(s).  just keep a global variable as the current "active" element (the last one clicked) and move it around whenever keydown.

Comment: Hi IT goldman...thank you for your idea, it is working to me

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me.

1-Remove the function code AddKeyboardEventToShape
2-Remove the code below.

stage.on('mousemove', function (e) {

```
   var container = stage.container();
   container.tabIndex = 0;
   container.focus(false);
   container.off('keydown');

   container.removeEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
   });

   return;
 });
```

3-Replace the code to replace stage.on('click') by code below

let shapeCliked;
const DELTA = 2;

stage.on('click', function (e) {

```
if (e.target === stage) {
    return;
}

shapeCliked = e.target;
var container = stage.container();

container.tabIndex = 1;
container.focus();

container.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            shapeCliked.x(shapeCliked.x() - DELTA);
            break;
        case 38:
            shapeCliked.y(shapeCliked.y() - DELTA);
            break;
        case 39:
            shapeCliked.x(shapeCliked.x() + DELTA);
            break;
        case 40:
            shapeCliked.y(shapeCliked.y() + DELTA);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

});